# PLTCL Function NEW($1) wont return desired result

Tags: postgresql, tcl

I have a PLTCL function runing from TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num() RETURNS trigger AS $$
spi_exec "UPDATE counter SET num = num + 1 WHERE tbl='$TG_table_name' RETURNING num"
set NEW('$1') $num
elog NOTICE "$1 --> [array get NEW]";
return [array get NEW]
$$ LANGUAGE pltcl STRICT;
```

But it returns NEW array with single quoted 'num'. Example:

```
18:49:38 NOTICE:  extra {} total 20000 id 31 'inv_num' 1 ts {2021-04-08 21:49:38.161285+02} fk_client 1
```

This is what I want to acomplish:

```
18:49:38 NOTICE:  extra {} total 20000 id 31 inv_num 1 ts {2021-04-08 21:49:38.161285+02} fk_client 1 

CREATE TRIGGER get_inv_number before insert ON invoice FOR EACH ROW   EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_num('inv_num');
CREATE TRIGGER get_pro_number before insert ON proforma FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_num('pro_num');
CREATE TRIGGER get_pay_number before insert ON payment FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_num('pay_num');
```

Thank you

Comment: ... leave out the single quotes in the `set` line?

Comment: It will give an ERROR:  bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

Comment: Using `set NEW($1) $num` gives an error like that? Must be doing interesting things with traces.

Comment: Include the relevant `CREATE TRIGGER` too?

Comment: In the body of the question, properly formatted so it's readable.

Comment: I've added CREATE TRIGGER statements in post

Comment: I don't know PL/TCL, but in PL/pgSQL a trigger function shouldn't return an array. Only a single record (the `new` record)

Comment: That's weird; that `elog` shouldn't produce that `NOTICE`; there's literal text missing…

Comment: This $NEW is from Postgres itself, An associative array containing the values of the new table row for INSERT or UPDATE actions, or empty for DELETE. From here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pltcl-trigger.html. These extra text you see in elog NOTICE is from my invoice table row. Actually example on official postgres site produces the same error

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution, instead of set NEW('$1') ... or set NEW($1) ... (WRONG from official PostgreSQL site) you need to do curly braces substitution like set NEW({$1}) ... :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    spi_exec "UPDATE counter SET num = num + 1 WHERE tbl='$TG_table_name' RETURNING num"
    set NEW(${1}) $num
    elog NOTICE "NEW ARRAY: [array get NEW]"
    return [array get NEW]
$$ LANGUAGE pltcl STRICT;
```

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: That's a good way of fooling the outer interpretation layer. Totally valid.